# How to change the layout of section titles

Tags: section-titles

I put the title of my examples in a single table cell to create a look of half a box around it with the following code

```
\newtheorem*{example}{\begin{tabular}{r|}example\\\hline\end{tabular}}
```

How can I do something similar for section titles? I tried:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\section{\begin{tabular}{r|}\\\hline\end{tabular}}
\makeatother
```

but this doesn't work.

A minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.5\linewidth}}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{1pt}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem*{example}{\begin{tabular}{r|}example\\\hline\end{tabular}}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@thm}{\thm@headpunct{.}}{\thm@headpunct{}}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section*{first}

\begin{example}
content
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps you should start by explaining what your overall end goal with this is. This seens rather strange to me.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: As already said in chat, please add a MWE (a short but compileable test document) to your question. How to customise the section layout heavily depends on your documentclass.

Comment: Have you tried the reverse approach, i.e., a single-cell tabular env. into the argument of `\section`?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I've added some part of my tex file.

Comment: @user91500 - No `\renewcommand`s. Just, say, `\section{\begin{tabular}{|c|} aa \\ bb \end{tabular}}`. I must confess that I, like the other commenters, am absolutely clueless as to what you're trying to achieve. Incidentally, the fact that you prefer to refuse to say what it is that you may be trying to achieve doesn't really help your cause.

Comment: How on earth can you have `\section` directives *before* `\begin{document}`?? This makes no sense at all. No wonder we're having major difficulties understanding what you're trying to do...

Comment: Following the comments I suggest to close this one, perhaps even delete it, to avoid using this approach. Doesn‘t sound useful to me.

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this question. It seems clear that the OP tries to change the format of section titles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `titlesec` package to redefine the layout of the section heading:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.5\linewidth}}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
%\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{1pt}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem*{example}{\begin{tabular}{r|}example\\\hline\end{tabular}}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@thm}{\thm@headpunct{.}}{\thm@headpunct{}}{}{}
\makeatother

\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}{\bfseries}{\thesection}{.5em}{\begin{tabular}{r|}#1\\\hline\end{tabular}}

\begin{document}

\section*{first}

\begin{example}
content
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works properly. Thank you.

Comment: @user91500 You're welcome!